# Rxjs: proper of Subject inside flatMap to avoid unexpected triggering

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5

I have an Angular "Quiz" application and use **rxjs 5.5.2** to implement a service with some business logic. I have an issue with my rxjs flow that causes unexpected execution of function multiple times.

The repro steps:

1. call *startNewQuiz* to set new quiz as active
2. call *answerQuestion* several times to answer quiz questions. Each answer triggers flow defined in constructor
3. call *startNewQuiz* once again to start another quiz

The problem is that on step 3 call to *startNewQuiz* triggers *doStuffWithQuiz* multiple times. Debugging shows that this is because *this.activeQuiz$* emits a value on step 3 and triggers *doStuffWithQuiz*. And since I have called *answerQuestion* multiple times before on step 2 - *doStuffWithQuiz* also called multiple times. The only reason of using *activeQuiz$* in the flow is to get current quiz and pass it futher to pipe.

I want my *answerQuestionSubject* flow to be executed only when I push something to *answerQuestionSubject* and avoid triggering of *doStuffWithQuiz* when something pushed to *activeQuiz$*.

**So how can I accomplish it?**

```
export class QuizFlowService {

  // to keep current active quiz
  private activeQuiz$ = new ReplaySubject<Quiz>(1);

  private answerQuestionSubject = new Subject<Answer>();

  ....

  constructor() {
    // setup flow for answers
    this.answerQuestionSubject.pipe(
      flatMap(
          // this is just to get active quiz and pass it futher
          () => this.activeQuiz$
      ),
      flatMap((quiz) => {
        // it is called multiple time on step 3
        doStuffWithQuiz(quiz)
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }

  // starts new quiz
  startNewQuiz(quiz: Quiz) {
    this.activeQuiz$.next(quiz);
  }

  // triggers answer flow
  answerQuestion(answer: Answer) {
    this.answerQuestionSubject.next(answer);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [first](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html) operator in your first flatMap

```
flatMap(
    () => this.activeQuiz$.first()
)
```

Since activeQuiz is a subject it can emit multiple times. (what is happening in step 3), however you are only concerned with the getting the active quiz (1 value). With first you will only listen for 1 value/emission.